# Image not displayed in WordPress.

Tags: php, wordpress, image, themes

I'm using the following inside images-options which is linked to `functions.php`. When clicked on submit button it crashes in WordPress admin.

```
<th scope="row">Image 1:</th> 
<td>
<input type="text" name="director_image1" value="<?php print get_option('director_image1'); ?>" />
<br/>
</td>
</tr>
```

I am using this to get the image in `header.php`.

```
var theImage=<?php $image = get_option('director_image1');?>
<?php if( $image) : ?>
<?php echo "'".$image."';"; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And finally i am using theImage variable inside a javascript file :

```
{
 src: theImage
 fade: 3000
 }
```

Could you please help me out the image is not being displayed.

Comment: <?php echo "'". $image."';" ?> in that line you have get only image src but for display you should use <img> tag.

Comment: @VishwaParekh Even if that were case, it wouldn't cause the server to throw an error, just the javascript which would appear in the console.

Comment: ya right but in html portion there was never use <img> tag so image is only display using img tag

Comment: @VishwaParekh could you guys please help me out

Comment: could you please help me out @anand-solanki

Comment: I think in $image variable you have to get image path means src. so you have to use image tag for that either in echo line or in <img> tag instead of <input> tag

Comment: Thanks vishwa let me try it out

Comment: Didn't work . You see i am using src in javascript

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i didn't add `,` after the link which is necessary in javascript. But i used `;` which is shouldn't be added after a link src in javascript.